# Passing array generated within a function to another called function (integration) in python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am doing numerical integration, where the function to be integrated is represented using cubic spline. The cubic spline is initiated in the function `MEcompute` as `splc`

Now the `integrand` which is actually doing the interpolation needs ths cubic spline array hence I need to pass the `splc` to this new function. And here I am stuck.

```
# function defining the integrand which uses the spline coef array to give interpolated values
def integrand(xpoint):
    spline_array=splc
    result=interpolate.splev(xpoint,spline_array,der=0)
    return result

#----------------------------------------
# function to the matrix element for certain rovibrational state
def MEcompute(psi1,psi2,psi_r, parameter, parameter_r ):

        # step 1: gen cubic spline coefs.
        splc=interpolate.splrep(parameter_r,parameter,s=0)

        # generate interpolated parameter for same xaxis as psi
        parameter_interp=interpolate.splev(psi_r,splc,der=0)

        # compute the pointwise products
        p1=np.multiply(psi1,psi2)
        p2=np.multiply(p1,psi_r)
        p3=np.multiply(p2,psi_r)
        product=np.multiply(p3,parameter_interp)

        # step 1: gen cubic spline coefs
        splc=interpolate.splrep(psi_r,product,s=0)

        # compute the integral using adaptive Quadrature
        #result=integrate.quadrature(integrand,0.2,4.48,tol=1.0e-9,maxiter=500)
        result=integrate.quadrature(integrand,0.2,4.48,tol=1.0e-9,maxiter=500)
        print("<psi1|parameter|psi2> = ",result)

#----------------------------------------
# computing the value

MEcompute(v1,v2,rwave,parameter1,distance)
#----------------------------------------
```

I receive the error,

```
NameError: name 'splc' is not defined
```

which happeds because the `integrand` function does not see the `splc` array initiated within the function `MEcompute`.

**Now I have one idea to get over this:**

1. Export the array `splc` from `MEcompute` maybe as a txt file, then load this txt file in the `integrand` function. This will definitely increase the computation time.

Can someone suggest a better way to do this.

Comment: Note that `(splc)` is not a tuple, but an expression in brackets, and you've mistyped the [keyword argument `args`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html).

Comment: Also, you have to make `splc` an explicit argument to `integrand`.

Comment: If you define the `integrand` function inside the `MEcompute` function, it can see all variables, including `splc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`args=` keyword argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html) to pass extra arguments to the function to integrate:

```
result = integrate.quadrature(integrand, 0.2, 4.48,
                              tol=1.0e-9, maxiter=500,
                              args=(splc,))
```

and modify your integrand to accept the argument:

```
def integrand(xpoint, splc):
    spline_array=splc
    result=interpolate.splev(xpoint,spline_array,der=0)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try defining `integrand` within `MEcompute`.

```
#----------------------------------------
# function to the matrix element for certain rovibrational state
def MEcompute(psi1,psi2,psi_r, parameter, parameter_r ):

        # step 1: gen cubic spline coefs.
        splc=interpolate.splrep(parameter_r,parameter,s=0)

        # function defining the integrand which uses the spline coef array to give interpolated values
        def integrand(xpoint):
            return interpolate.splev(xpoint,splc,der=0)

        # generate interpolated parameter for same xaxis as psi
        parameter_interp=interpolate.splev(psi_r,splc,der=0)

        # compute the pointwise products
        p1=np.multiply(psi1,psi2)
        p2=np.multiply(p1,psi_r)
        p3=np.multiply(p2,psi_r)
        product=np.multiply(p3,parameter_interp)

        # step 1: gen cubic spline coefs
        splc=interpolate.splrep(psi_r,product,s=0)

        # compute the integral using adaptive Quadrature
        #result=integrate.quadrature(integrand,0.2,4.48,tol=1.0e-9,maxiter=500)
        result=integrate.quadrature(integrand,0.2,4.48,tol=1.0e-9,maxiter=500)
        print("<psi1|parameter|psi2> = ",result)

#----------------------------------------
# computing the value

MEcompute(v1,v2,rwave,parameter1,distance)
#----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution works but I can select only one accepted answer.